# AvalonDock : Programmatically undock DocumentContents of DocumentPan

Tags: wpf, avalondock

Hi I was wondering if I could undock all `DocumentContent`s of a `DocumentPan` programmatically .

any Suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've spend couple of hours on this problem and found following solution. I downloaded avalon's source code and modified it. I've made two modifications. The first one in DocumentPane class:

```
public void UnDock(DockableContent content)
    {
        DockingManager manager = GetManager();
        Point point = this.PointToScreenDPI(new Point(0, 0));
        manager.Drag(content, point, new Point(0, 0));
        manager.CompleteDragging(point);
    }
```

And the second, I extent visibility of CompleteDragging method from private to internal.

Usage of UnDock is quite simple:

```
dockumentPane1.UnDock(dockablePane1.Items[0] as DockableContent);
```

Of course DocumentPane should contain some DockableContent and it should be exactly DockableContent not DocumentContent.
It seems work fine for me ;)

Comment: Thank you, how can i maximize it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
void undockAll(LayoutDocumentPane pane)
{
    while(pane.Children.Count > 0)
       pane.Children[0].Float();
}
```